# Why does my mongodb nodejs driver query on aggregate $lookup not return results as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: `users` and `roles`

The users have an array of roles assigned to them:

```
{
    _id : 61582a79fd033339c73ee290
    roles:[615825966bc7d715021ce8fc, 615825966bc7d715021ce8fd]
}
```

roles:

```
[
   {
     _id: 615825966bc7d715021ce8fc
     name: 'user',
   },
   {
     _id: 615825966bc7d715021ce8fd
     name: 'admin',
   },
]
```

As you can see the user has an array of object ids that correspond to the roles.

I have a $lookup aggregate query where I'm trying to return all users with the roles populated:

```
dbManager.aggregate = async () => {
    let a = dbInstance.collection('users').aggregate(
        [
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: 'roles',
                    localField: 'roles',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'user_roles'
                }
            }
        ]
    )
    console.log('a:::::::', a)
}
```

When I run this query: `dbManager.aggregate()`, I get a very big object and I don't see the user information anywhere nor how to extract it. According to the documentation, this should return the information I'm querying. Here's the first few fields of what it returns as I don't want to overwhelm with the huge object:

```
AggregationCursor {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
 [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
 [Symbol(topology)]: Topology {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      topologyDescriptionChanged: [Array],
    }
  ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: put `await` before query `let a = await dbInstance.collection('users').aggregate(`

Comment: Tried that earlier. No luck. Thanks for replying!

Comment: As per this [node mongo native](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#aggregate) documentation, it will return Aggregation Cursor Instance Class, you can put callback function as the last parameter in aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I have to call `.toArray` which returns a promise that resolves the data:

```
dbManager.aggregate = async () => {
    let a = await dbInstance.collection('users').aggregate(
        [
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: 'roles',
                    localField: 'roles',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'user_roles'
                }
            }
        ]
    )
     .toArray().then(data => data)
     .catch(e => console.log(e))
    console.log('a:::::::', a)
}
```

It kind of sucks that nowhere on the page does it say to do this on the MongoDB documentation but glad I could find a solution!